# .net index class inheritance

Tags: .net, inheritance, indexer

i try to create a index class for all my classes in my Project.

eg.

class whatever:

```
public class cWhatEver : cBase
{

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The class whatever inherits the the cBase-class:

```
public abstract class cBase : IBase, System.ICloneable
{

    private static Int64 _Count;
    private Int64 _ID;

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public Int64 ID {
        get { return _ID; }
    }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public Int64 Count {
        get { return _Count; }
    }

    public cBase()
    {
        cBase._Count += 1;
        this._ID = cBase._Count - 1;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        cBase newClone = (cBase)base.MemberwiseClone();
        cBase._Count += 1;
        newClone._ID = cBase._Count - 1;
        return newClone;
    }

    protected override void Finalize()
    {
        _Count -= 1;
    }
}
```

But when the classes are created i always get the count of all items in all classes, which inherits cBase, instead of the count of class( of T) or the ids.

Say class whatever has 5 items, and class whatever_1 has 10 items then the count is 15, instead of 5 and 10, and the id's also counted over all items

So how do i index that right. Maybe some1 can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: I know you likely came from Java or something else that uses `camelCase` for its class names but [the .NET naming standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) state that classes should be `PascelCase`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: `cBase` - I'm betting on a C/++ background.

Comment: Is that your actual code? I don't think so, because it's not legal to override Finalize; you have to declare a destructor instead.

Comment: thx for the answers...try to adapt that for my needs and to precise it a little...sry im new to this and struggle a little with all the .net stuff :) The goal is to get a indexer-class for all my classes in the project Every Item of T should have an ID, so i can get every item of the class over the id, and the count of items of class(of T) which increases/decreases automaticly. So i need T.count and T(index) for all classes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to maintain a count of instances of each class in the hierarchy. The problem is that the `_Count` field is shared between all instances of `cBase`, including derived classes.

A possible solution would be to take advantage of the fact that distinct realizations of a generic class have their own distinct copies of static fields, i.e., if you have this class:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    private static int _count;
}
```

Then `Foo<int>` and `Foo<string>` won't share their `_count` field.

Now, how to apply this to your problem? Well, there is a famous and kind of weird pattern, called the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), that makes use of generics in an unusual way (*). As it happens, the Wikipedia article gives an example that applies exactly to your problem.

You define a base class like this:

```
abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    private static long _count;
    public static long Count { get { return _count; } }

    public Base()
    {
        _count++;
    }
}
```

(note how the type parameter is constrained to derived from the generic type itself)

Then you can create derived classes like this:

```
class Derived1 : Base<Derived1> { }
class Derived2 : Base<Derived2> { }
```

These classes are both subclasses of `Base<T>`, but they also have different type parameters, so they won't share their static fields. If you do this:

```
var d1 = new[] {new Derived1(), new Derived1(), new Derived1(), new Derived1()};
var d2 = new[] {new Derived2(), new Derived2()};
Console.WriteLine("Derived1: {0}", Derived1.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Derived2: {0}", Derived2.Count);
```

You get the desired result:

```
Derived1: 4
Derived2: 2
```

---

(*) Actually this pattern originally comes from C++ and is based on templates, not generics, but it translates quite well to C# and other languages that support generics.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do such thing is beyond me really, but basically problem is that the *_count* field exists only once, not one counter for each class type derived from it.

A possible alternative would be to use a `Dictionary<Type,Int64>`, that holds one different counter for each class type created, then increment only the relevant one:

```
public abstract class cBase : IBase, System.ICloneable
{
    private static Dictionary<Type,Int64> _counts;

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public Int64 Count
    {
        get { return _counts[this.GetType()]; }
    }

    public cBase()
    {
        if(this._counts.Contains(this.GetType())
            this._counts[this.GetType()] = this._counts[this.GetType()]  +1;
        else
            this._counts.Add(this.GetType(),1);

        this._ID = this._count[this.GetType()] - 1;
    }

    protected override void Finalize()
    {
        this._counts[this.GetType()] = this._counts[this.GetType()] - 1;
    }
}
```